# Why does foldRight of a list return a future and not a new list?

Tags: scala, promise, future

Given this code which converts a List[Future[T]] to Future[List[T]]

```
def all[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[List[T]] = {

  val p = Promise[List[T]]() //create an empty promise which will contain the result (i.e. the future)
  p.success(Nil) //initialise: the result of the promise is a Future of an empty list
  fs.foldRight(p.future) { //accumulator is the future of the promise
    (oneFutueFromTheList, accFutureOfAList) =>
      for (
        actualValueOfFuture <- oneFutueFromTheList; //unpack the item in the future
        theList <- accFutureOfAList //unpack the list from the future
      ) yield actualValueOfFuture :: theList //append the item to the list
  }

}
```

The yield of the for comprehension is a List[T].

Why does the foldRight return a Future[List[T]] (and not a List[T])? Is it because the accumulator of the foldRight is a Future[List[T]] and the foldRight is "clever" enough to know to put the result List[T] of the yield into a Future[List[T]] ?

Source of the code: https://class.coursera.org/reactive-001 Principles of Reactive Programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for comprehension is just synthetic sugar for flatMaps and maps so this loop is actually:

```
oneFutueFromTheList.flatMap(actualValueOfFuture =>
  accFutureOfAList.map(theList =>
    actualValueOfFuture :: theList))
```

The signature of foldRight is: `foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B`
The foldRight takes the z as the initialized value and for every item it run the op function. The op function should return value of the type Z which in this case is a List[T]. The op function is now run again this time Z is the last op return value. This continue for all the items in the collection.
The return value of the foldRight is the last Z returned from the op function.

Comment: So the map takes the List[T] (actualValueOfFutre::theList) and "packs" that into a Future[List[T]].

Answer (score 2):

Because `p.future` is a `Future[List[T]]` and the signature of `foldRight` is `foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) ⇒ B): B`.

In this case, `z` is `p.future` so `B` is `Future[List[T]]`.

Comment: So the type of the accumulator (z:B) determines the type of the result and Scala under the hood ensures that the list (from the for comprehension / yield) becomes the value of the future?